# Error in image file upload using dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

Greeting to you all!

Please I need you PRO help. My case seem similar to some of the ones I have seen but my code is completely different.

I wrote this code below using PHP in Dreamweaver and its used to upload images to MySQl database. Now when I upload about 6 images, it shows **File Uploaded Successfully**. But if I try to upload any thing below 6 images, it will refuse to upload and will echo **Upload Failed**.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $projid=$_POST['projid'];
  $projname=$_POST['projname'];

  $name=basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
  $t_name=$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
  $dir='upload';
  if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))

  $nameone=basename($_FILES['file_uploadone']['name']);
  $t_name=$_FILES['file_uploadone']['tmp_name'];
  $dir='upload1';
  if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))

  $nametwo=basename($_FILES['file_uploadtwo']['name']);
  $t_name=$_FILES['file_uploadtwo']['tmp_name'];
  $dir='upload2';

  if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
  $namethree=basename($_FILES['file_uploadthree']['name']);
  $t_name=$_FILES['file_uploadthree']['tmp_name'];
  $dir='upload3';

  if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
  $namefour=basename($_FILES['file_uploadfour']['name']);
  $t_name=$_FILES['file_uploadfour']['tmp_name'];
  $dir='upload4';
  if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))

  $namefive=basename($_FILES['file_uploadfive']['name']);
  $t_name=$_FILES['file_uploadfive']['tmp_name'];
  $dir='upload5';
  if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
{
    mysql_select_db ($database_ProjMonEva,$ProjMonEva);
    $qur="insert into tbl_images (imageid, projid, projname, name, path, nameone, pathone, nametwo, pathtwo, namethree, paththree, namefour, pathfour, namefive, pathfive) values ('','$projid','$projname','$name','upload/$name','$nameone','upload/$nameone','$nametwo','upload/$nametwo','$namethree','upload/$namethree','$namefour','upload/$namefour','$namefive','upload/$namefive')";
    $res=mysql_query($qur,$ProjMonEva);
    echo 'File uploaded successful';    
}
else
{
    echo 'upload failed!';
}
}
?>
<?php
```

I see the problem to come from the echo but I am stock and dont know how to correct it. Can any one please help me.

Thank you in advance
Mike

Comment: Horrible code.... you absolutely **HAVE** to check if an upload was performed, and that it actually succeeded. Your code is blindly assuming there will ALWAYS be sixuploads, and all six will ALWAYS succeed.

Comment: Hi Marc, your comment is true but what is your suggestion? I am still learning and stock. Can you help me out with a sample function I can write to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve the issue. You can view the code update here http://forums.adobe.com/message/6132524#6132524

Check the last post on the page.

Thank you for your help.

Prince Mike

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a condition `if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))` but then you are not indicating what happens if the condition is met so only the first line (just after the if) is taken as what to do if the condition is met.

In fact you are only doing it once correctly using `{}`:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
{
    mysql_select_db ($database_ProjMonEva,$ProjMonEva);
    $qur="insert into tbl_images (imageid, projid, projname, name, path, nameone, pathone, nametwo, pathtwo, namethree, paththree, namefour, pathfour, namefive, pathfive) values ('','$projid','$projname','$name','upload/$name','$nameone','upload/$nameone','$nametwo','upload/$nametwo','$namethree','upload/$namethree','$namefour','upload/$namefour','$namefive','upload/$namefive')";
    $res=mysql_query($qur,$ProjMonEva);
    echo 'File uploaded successful';    
}
```

The best thing you can do is to create a function and for each loaded file call the function.

Comment: @user3201606; Thank you for your comment. Please can you help me out? I need help please. Thank you

Comment: The best thing you can do is to create a function and for each loaded file call the function.

Comment: Hi Malta, please I am still getting used to Php. Can you help out? I have never written a function before and dont know how to start from here

Comment: Hello Friends, I am still hoping that some one will help me out here please..................

Comment: Hi Malta, can I move the MySQL insertion code from the last line to a different location and add the condition code to each of the upload? DO you think that can help?

Comment: read more about functions - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php. Put the SQL query in the function and then call it whenever necsssary.